# מורה vs. הורה - Implication in difference of the word

Tags: words, children-parenting, chinuch-education, samson-raphael-hirsch

It seems that the hebrew words for Teacher and Parent are the same root which means to teach.

I am looking for what the מ  (מורה) and (הורה) ה do to the words that help define their roles.

**Update: (In response to if the words are truly connected)** [image: Rav Hirsch on Harah]

I am not an expert on root words. I was shown this from Rav Hirsch which seems to be a source that הורה can also mean to teach.

And one more anecdote: "כל המלמד בן חבירו תורה מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו ילדו" - I think we can say that this would imply a connection between parenting and teaching as well.

So going with that can anyone help me with what the prefixes might imply?

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect to Rav Hirsch, it seems that the words come from different roots.

Teacher comes from [י-ר-ה/י](https://hebrew-academy.org.il/%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9C/?action=netiot&shoresh=%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%99&binyan=40) in the *hiph'il* (infinitive לְהוֹרוֹת, meaning to instruct or teach.) [Gesenius](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Gesenius/index.htm) on ירה writes:

> Derived nouns, תורה ,מורה ,יורה

Parent comes from [ה-ר-ה/י](https://hebrew-academy.org.il/%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%99%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%9C/?action=netiot&shoresh=%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99&binyan=0) in the *kal* (infinitive לַהֲרוֹת, to conceive). See Rashi and ibn Ezra to [Bereishis 49:26](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.49.26?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.49.26&lang2=bi&p3=Ibn_Ezra_on_Genesis.49.26.1&lang3=bi), and [Gesenius](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Gesenius/index.htm) on הרה:

> The Hebrew interpreters also consider the plural הורים to be as if by zeugma ... to be put for parents.

(Also see [Menachem ibn Saruq](https://www.sefaria.org/Mahberet_Menachem%2C_Letter_Bet.1.29?lang=he) who groups words such as ולהורות ,הורני ,המורה together with ירה יירה ,ויורו המורים separately from words related to [conception](https://www.sefaria.org/Mahberet_Menachem%2C_Letter_Heh.22.3?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).)

Comment: Interesting. What's your source? Also, what would the mem vs. hey do as a prefix of a word if it was the same root?

Comment: See the sources quoted that link הורה to conception rather than instruction as you assumed.

Comment: What would your hypothetical same root be?

Comment: Please see my updated question - I think there is room to see these root words as connected.

Comment: Joel K: How about the words הוציא and מוציא?

Comment: Root is י-צ-א conjugated in the *hiph'il*. הוציא is perfect tense (he took out), מוציא is present participle (taking out).

Comment: Interesting. Do you think the application here can be passive (parent)/active (teacher) teaching?

Comment: I don't see any indication of passive vs active here. WADR to R Hirsch, there could very well be a connection between the two words at the level of *derush*, but I don't think attempting an analysis using the rules of Hebrew grammar is going to be very productive: מורה cannot be formed from the root הרה using standard grammatical constructs.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [chart](https://www.pealim.com/dict/3268-kidomet/) which implies:

That a ה would create a noun so perhaps this is conveying that the parent has the real teacher "identity" whereas the מ is an adjective so perhaps more of a supportive role?

Alternatively, it could be that a noun is more general and an adjective is more specific so perhaps a teacher is someone who teaches specific topics but a parent is more of an instructor on everything?

[Please debate/support either of these in the comments]

Comment: I’m pretty sure that מורה is a noun, not an adjective